# SPARQL algebra: tricky ASK from named graphs if any triples do not exist

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, linked-data, triples, named-graphs

Take these two named graphs:

```
# graph :yesterday
:Foo 
     :likes :Bar ;
     :likes :Qux .

# graph :today
:Foo
    :likes :Bar ;
    :likes :Baz .
```

Now say you want to find out if any of the triples from graph `:yesterday` are absent from graph `:today`. How would you `ASK` this query?

```
ASK
FROM NAMED :yesterday
FROM NAMED :today
{
    GRAPH :yesterday {
        ?s ?p ?o .
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPARQL has two operations for negation : use the one you find most natural. As I read the problem description, it read more like the first one below to me but in this problem situation they are very similar.  They differ in their effects when one part or other of the pattern does not match anything or when there are no variables in common.

`NOT EXISTS` tests for the absence of a pattern (there is `EXISTS` as well).  It is a filter applied to each solution of the first pattern.  It is like a nested `ASK` where also that the variables are substituted for the incoming ones to the filter.

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example/>
SELECT * {
  GRAPH :yesterday { ?s ?p ?o }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { GRAPH :today { ?s ?p ?o } }
}
```

`MINUS` executes the two patterns (left and right sides) and then returns the rows of the left where there is no matching one anywhere on the right.  It is an anti-join.

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example/>
SELECT * {
  GRAPH :yesterday { ?s ?p ?o }
  MINUS { GRAPH :today { ?s ?p ?o } }
}
```

For both I get:

```
------------------------
| s    | p      | o    |
========================
| :Foo | :likes | :Qux |
------------------------
```

TriG:

```
@prefix : <http://example/> .

:yesterday {
  :Foo 
     :likes :Bar ;
     :likes :Qux .
}

:today {
  :Foo
    :likes :Bar ;
    :likes :Baz .
}
```

Comment: Feeling a bit stupid right now for forgetting the right named graph when I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my filter not exists block wasn't filtering out `:Bar`. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyway, I hope others finds this useful in the future.